# Keep scroll position in an element on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, page-refresh

I set a ul of product variants with horizontal scroll.
When i scroll and click on a variant the page refresh and the scroll return to start.
I need to maintain the posistion where it was first of refresh.

How can i do?

```css
ul#group_17 {
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
    list-style: none;
}
li {margin: 0 10px 0 0}
.input-color {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
}
span {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="group_17">
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="87">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:black"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="88" checked="checked">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:brown;"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="89">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:red"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class="float-xs-left input-container">
    <label>
      <input class="input-color" type="radio" data-product-attribute="17" name="group[17]" value="90">
      <span class="color texture" style="background:yellow"></span>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The most important place to start is [mcve]. That will allow you to post your question in a way that will allow people to assist you in the most effective manner.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I added more information. I hope it can be usefull

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed
But you can give an ID to the part of your code that you want and when you click, it will be linked to the same part

Comment: I added more information. Can you explain me what can i do? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code in js

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

or use this in js

```
  <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
            var scrollpos = localStorage.getItem('scrollpos');
            if (scrollpos) window.scrollTo(0, scrollpos);
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            localStorage.setItem('scrollpos', window.scrollY);
        };
    </script>
```